# Cups, permission denied

Tags: linux, cups

Running CUPS on linux.

- Open of http://thehost:631 displays CUPS overview page as expected
- Click on admin (http://thehost:631/admin) brings "Internal Server Error" and log ends with:

  **PID 5892 (/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi) stopped with status 113 (Permission denied)**
- I can run /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi from command line without any issues and get some output
- I looked into the CUPS sources: The error comes from execv(). errno# 13 is permission denied. (+100 is added for some CUPS reasons)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wrong forum, nothing to do with programming. Flagged for move to **Super User**.

Comment: I compiled cups from sources and applied some patches. But the unmodified version of the developer board worked without any issues. Thus I placed the question here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- Found reason: Permissions of filesystem were not set
- Details: Some files belongs to a user not existing. This was the user build the system and installed some components
- Fix: Set right permissions for the whole tree and not even for some subfolders

Set user rights:

```
chown -R root:root /usr
chown -R root:root /shared
```

Previously I tried with `chown -R root:root /usr/etc/cups` but this was not sufficient.

Comment: Won't this attempt to change the ownership of every file on the filesystem? That seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: You are right. I modified my answer.

Comment: This is still far too broad; you should not recursively change permissions on the entire /usr directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is running under a user that does not have permission to execute `/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi`. When you are running it from command line you are executing it as a different user which has sufficient permissions to execute it.

Check under which user your web server is running and change the file permissions of `/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi` to make it accessible to the web server. You can read more about file permissions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes).

regards.

Comment: That was my assumption to. But with **ps** I see that **/usr/sbin/cupsd** is running as **root**. And within the log the environment of the subprocess is printed out with: 'D [10/Sep/2015:11:43:41 +0200] [CGI] envp[14] = "USER=root"'

Comment: I'm not on Linux currently so I can't check, but I very much doubt that cupsd is the webserver, AFAIK it's only a print deamon, look more closely what part of cups is the web server that us executing admin.cgi and check its permissions.

Comment: CUPS is the webserver to. A few sprintfs of html tags are sufficient for most use cases. A sledgehammer is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

On my platform (elementary OS / an Ubuntu fork), the CUPS package did not correctly set permissions on its own directories. I needed to change permission on /usr/lib/cups to get things working:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/cups
```

I did not have to restart the service -- this was purely a permissions issue. I have not been able to add printers via the GUI (yet), and assume there are further underlying issues involved -- for example, all files in the CUPS directory structure are owned root:root... probably the p"group needs to be in there somewhere.